# Invisible wall that doesnt appear during modelling, but on rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera

In the blend file attached, I want to render rgb frames at various camera viewpoints.
[image]

When I render a frame at the camera pose shown in the screenshot (facing the counter), only a white image is rendered. [image]
However, as apparent from the global view, there is no plane in front of the camera. I get a white image for all camera poses at thetha-z = 180 and y > 3.5 (approx).
How do I get rid of this white 'wall'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an object just named “Cube” that is hidden in viewports, but not in renders:

[image]

This object obscures the camera:

[image]

Either delete the object or disable it for renders as well, and your problem will be resolved.